# Linkage error of extern const string

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, hyperlink

I got the following linkage problem.

in a 1st compile unit, I define in the global space e a `const string`like below:

```
const string test_string = "blahblah";
```

Later, in a 2dn compile unit I wanted to reuse that string and I wrote:

```
extern string test_string;
```

but the linkage process failed (**undefined symbol**) and the only way I found to link was to use `const char*` instead of `const string`.

I would like to understand why it happens ?

Comment: Could you post the `gcc` command you are using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, `string` and `const string` are different types. So the two declarations of `test_string` could never match.

There's one more issue, though. A variable declared `const`, and not explicitly declared `extern`, has *internal linkage* (which basically means it's implicitly `static`).

Normally, if you want to share a constant between translation units, you would define it in a header and include that in all of them; each of them would then get its own identical copy.

If you actually want to share a single instance of it, you must mark the variable for external linkage when defining it in the 1st unit:

```
extern const string test_string = "blahblah";
```

Then, you can just declare it to access it from the 2nd unit:

```
extern const string test_string;
```

Again, don't forget the `const`, as the types must match.

As to why it works with `const char *`; there, the `const`applies to the pointed-to characters, not to the pointer. So the pointer itself has normal external linkage. You'd get the same error as with the `string` if you had made it `const char * const`.

Comment: I fact the 'missing' `const` was a mistake in the post, but your answer is really clear anyway !